# How can I correct odometry using rtabmap?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that rtabmap uses loop closure to correct the odometry error but did I turn it on, that is the question.
What parameter should I turn on to activate the loop closure or is it turned on by default?

Also, having the wheel odometry, is it worth to also turn on the stereo odometry? If yes, how can I fuse them both?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327032/how-can-i-correct-odometry-using-rtabmap?/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the following parameters will help you:

`<param name="RGBD/ProximityBySpace"        type="string" value="true"/>`   is for
Local loop closure detection (using estimated position) with locations in WM

`<param name="Reg/Strategy"                 type="string" value="2"/>` is for Loop closure transformation: 0=Visual, 1=ICP, 2=Visual+ICP

---

Originally posted by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) with karma: 210 on 2019-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-06-26**:
@kosmastsk isn't ICP stands for the lidar odometry? I only have the wheel odometry

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2019-06-26**:
You're right! Take a look in here:  http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot
RTAB-Map gives you the way to syncronize all of the odometry sources, or you can just ignore the laser odometry and use only the wheel odometry . You can remap the odom topic to the topic of your wheel odometry.
Also, ICP is not for a specific odometry type, it is an alignment method that leads to loop closure, independent of the source of odometry

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-06-26**:
@kosmastsk Ok, so the second param would be value=0 as I will only use visual